# Associate color values from Storyboard to enum or struct

Tags: ios, swift, colors, enums, uistoryboard

How I can associate color values from Storyboard to code without subclassing?

The problem is, that in our product we have different brands. So we have some controls like buttons, text fields, labels that have different color by brand.

I guess that I can subclass every control and use a @IBInspectable to select the color from a enum, and this enum can search for the specific brand color. But there are too many places to do this job and I think that is not scalable.

The main target is to have a unique place to change the color value. Now we have some colors in code and in storyboard views, and when a color changes we have to change code and each view in storyboard.

I'm trying to found a solution like Android xml colors files

Answer (score 2):

The official apple way for doing this is with the [UIAppearance](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiappearance) proxy.  You can also globally set the tint color with UIApplication.shared().delegate?.window?.tintColor = .red

Comment: yes, but you are not able to see the color in storyboard

Comment: The android version is better with the color and string constants, but unfortunately apple hasn't implemented color and string varible support in interface builder.  You can make custom color palettes in XCode but you can't use them as variables.  The storyboards are XML so if you need to quickly statically re-theme things the fastest way is to actually find and replace the text.  I wish I had a better answer but thats the way it works.